# Python: dict comprehension from a list with key and value being strings?

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I want to turn a list `('a','b','c')` into `{'1':'a','2':'b','3':'c'}`

```
 d = {key: value for key, value in targets}
```

returns keys as integer, I need it to be stored as a string so that I can append a string to each of the keys so that eventually I will end up with

```
{'column1','a','column2','b','column3'}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just cast the key to `str()` and `enumerate()`:

```
d = {str(i): value for i, value in enumerate(targets)}
```

or use formatting if you need to prepend the keys with a string:

```
d = {'column{}'.format(i): value for i, value in enumerate(targets)}
```

The key and value expressions in a dict comprehension are just that, python expressions.

Comment: so awesome, simply cannot do this in Java as elegantly

Comment: @KimJongWoo: The dict comprehension syntax was added in Python 2.7; use `dict(('column{}'.format(i), value) for i, value in enumerate(targets))` in earlier versions.

Comment: yes I ended up using dict() instead. nevertheless, it's very powerful.

Comment: `d = {'column{}'.format(i): value for i, value in enumerate(targets)}` i am not able to track how `i` is being managed - please help!